# asus zenbook prime keyboard

Tags: keyboard, zenbook

Recently my Zenbook prime's keyboard has had issues with its keyboard. Randomly, various keys will just stop working. Sometimes they work if I continually press them...sometimes not.

Any idea what's going on here? Dirt behind the keys? Faulty keyboard?

I'm not sure how to remove the keys...plus I don't want to ruin the keyboard. Do you guys know how to remove the keyboard on the zenbook prime?

Comment: I haven't had my hands on one, but I am led to believe these things have crappy keyboards.

Comment: You can *probably* use a keycap puller. As for the keyboard itself, it's not the Prime but I found a guide for a related model [here](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Asus+Zenbook+UX32VD+Teardown/10120). Looking at it though, wouldn't recommend it if you don't have prior experience.